# laravel vite vue blade

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, vite

I have installed laravel + vite + vue. If I use this code and 'npm run dev' , i allways see only vue component. Not render blade (I can't see the text in this case). What's wrong?

index.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Laravel 9 with vue 3 vite</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <calendar-component></calendar-component>
        <p>Sample text</p>
    </div>
    @vite('resources/js/app.js')
</body>

</html>
```

app.js

```
import "./bootstrap";
import { createApp } from "vue";

import CalendarComponent from "./components/CalendarComponent.vue";

createApp(CalendarComponent).mount("#app");
```

app.js - new

```
    import "./bootstrap";
     import { createApp } from "vue";
     import CalendarComponent from "./components/CalendarComponent.vue";
                     
 const app = createApp({
            components: {
                CalendarComponent,
            },
        });
        
        app.mount("#app");
```

Comment: Is that your full `index.blade.php`? How does the relevant controller look like?

Comment: It's only sample. why is this happening

Answer (score 0):

By calling `.mount("#app")` you will mount the vue application instance in your `<div id="app"></div>` element.

Assuming your `CalendarComponent` has a template this will "replace any existing DOM nodes inside the container" (See [docs](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-mount)).

If you want to mix vue and blade you could change your `index.blade.html` body to something like this:

```
<div id="blade">
    <p>Sample text</p>
</div>
<div id="app"></div>
@vite('resources/js/app.js')
```

Comment: Thank you tobifasc for explain. But in project with laravel, vue and webpack  i have have code and works. Not replace the existing DOM only render vue and blade: <body>

   

    <div  id="app">

            
            @yield('content')

        </main>

Comment: I'm sorry i don't understand the comment. Maybe you can edit your question to clarify

Comment: The same code as in the question, in laravel+vue3+webpack configuration works fine. It will display the calendar + "Sample text". However, in the laravel + vue3 + vite configuration, it will only display the calendar without text (it will replace the DOM as you wrote above). Why is it like that?

Comment: How does your `index.blade.html` look like when using webpack?

Comment: for simplicity, I replaced @yield with <p> in my main question.                              
 ```<body>
    <div id="app">
      <main class="main-content">
        
            @yield('content')
        </main>
      
    </div>
</body>```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the differences between your 2 configs. Maybe then i can try to edit my answer to explain why they behave differently.

Comment: Resolved. "Problem" has been with app.js. Vite created createApp(CalendarComponent).mount("#app").  In webpack i have objects components:  const app = createApp({
    components: {
        component
    },
});

app.mount("#app");

Comment: This means that your root component **doesn't have a template** but rather just a locally registered component (`createApp({ components: {component}});`). What i still don't understand is that you would have to provide a correct template in your `index.blade.php` for your component to be mounted? Just `<p>Sample text</p>` wouldn't work. It would really help to see your full code.

Comment: Still glad that you resolved it. I would have just liked to give a helpful answer for you

Comment: I have updated code in my question. Look at app.js difference. "Old" app replace all DOM inside div. New version of app.js file, allows you to insert a component inside div and render (in this case) <p> tag. I hope you understood :). Vite and Webpack have nothing to do with it :). Thank You for your willingness to help .

Comment: I have some problem. JS:

`import {createApp} from "vue";
import SearchComponent from "./components/SearchComponent.vue";
const app = createApp({components: {SearchComponent}});
app.mount('#app');`
HTML(Blade):

`<div id="app">
        @yield('content')
        </div>`
When run it, all DOM elements in the #app div will be removed. 

Why? How to resolve this?

Comment: Check the link to vue docs i postet in my answer. `app.mount('#app')` will replace the existing elements in your `div`

Answer (score 0):

Solve it for Vue 3.

In the `vite.config.js` need add a alias for vue:

```
export default defineConfig({
    ....
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
        },
    },
})
```